# How to install packages in python

Tags: python, git, installation, package

Hi I am completely new to Python, and I would like to install [Python-LinkedIn](https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin)
in order to extract data from the LinkedIn API.

I have installed the files into the same directory as all my other packages (including `pip`). I'm not sure if this is how to do it.

Whenever I type:

```
pip install python-linkedin
```

it returns

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Whenever I type:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin.git
```

or

```
pip clone git+https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin.git
```

it returns

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Help please, I just need to know how to get started, thank you.

Comment: have u installed `pip`? OS based?

Comment: Yes i've installed pip, I am using windows

Comment: Which version of python do you have: 2+ or 3+?

Comment: Have you tried `python install setup.py` after changing the directory to point to the python-Linked folder?

Comment: make sure you're in C:\Pythonxx\Scripts directory?

Comment: @doru i have python 2.7.10

Comment: @Vaulstein Hi yes, it still shows "invalid syntax"

Comment: You'll get that syntax error if you try to run `pip install` **in the Python interpreter**, rather than on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

given that you are in windows (which it would seem like)

open command prompt and type

```
[path to your python_folder]\scripts\pip.exe install [package name]
```

for example if your python is installed in C:\ and you are using 2.7.

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe install Python-LinkedIn
```

(or `pip[versionumber].exe`)

Answer (score 1):

So like [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) mentioned before you are trying to install it from within python interpreter and you should do it from command line instead.
Under Windows just press window key on keyboard, type cmd and press enter and then type that (of course it works if python is added to path, if not, navigate to its scripts folder):

```
pip install python-linkedin
```

On OS X, open your Applications folder, then open the Utilities folder. Open the Terminal application.

I hope this will be helpful. Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to install python modules is PyPy. See the page of the module at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-linkedin . It includes installation instructions.

```
$ pip install python-linkedin
```

Comment: @Vaulstein: you should put the command into the command-line (console, terminal), not Python REPL. See [The Command Line Crash Course](http://cli.learncodethehardway.org/book/)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Abi did not mention he typed it in the Python REPL. I was assuming he did it in the console. Like who wouldn't.

Comment: @Vaulstein: `SyntaxError` hints at that. Unless the material is for a complete beginner; nobody mentions that you should run `pip` in the command-line.